# How do i bind input field (from DB to UI / UI to DB) with an autocomplete option in angular material?

Tags: angular

while using angular material table , i wanted to have an editable cell with an input field that has an autocomplete functionality. The datasource for the table is different from the source of the autocomplete option. I am able to make the autocomplete work but i couldn't make the two way binding work for the initial population from Database or after a user changes the values.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="outputProductCode">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Output Product Code</mat-header-cell>
      
      <td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
        <mat-form-field >
          <input type="text" aria-label="ProductCode" matInput [(ngModel)]="row.outputProductCode" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="myControl">
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete"  (optionSelected)="saveProductCode(row, $event.option.value)" >
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
              {{option}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

just subscribe to the valueChanges event like this =>

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getOptions().subscribe((options: Option) => {
    this.options = options;
    this.filteredOptions = this.marketCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith<string | Option>(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this.filterOption(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
  });
}

private filterOption(value: string): Market[] {
  return this.options.filter(market => this.contains(option.name, value));
}
```

And pleaaaaaase do not forget to unsubscribe using ngOnDestroy unless you wanna end up with a heavy memory consuming app!